# Long TTFB in File Upload request only at Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, https, xmlhttprequest, cloudflare

I have an upload field in a form that uploads the file via ajax, and "attaches" it to the form to send it along.
What is happening is that the request to upload the file is taking a crazy long time in Chrome to complete. It works normally on my browser (Opera).

The Server/Environment Specs:

- Apache server
- Linux OS
- Using Cloudflare
- *If you need any other information, just ask!*

Analysing the XHRs, you can see the huge difference, just to be clear: this was the upload of the **same file, same network, same computer,** just **different browsers**. You see the sending time is almost the same, but the Wait Time (or TTFB) is very different.

Opera:

[image: Opera]

---

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Is there any reason for this? I read something about Chrome having threading limits, but doesn't seem to be the reason for this.